# Kubernetes ELB service: How to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, tls1.0

I am running Kubernetes on AWS, and exposing services using a `Service` with `type: LoadBalancer`, which provisions an ELB. Is there any way to control the ELB cipher configuration with annotations on this service? I need to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

I am aware that I can do this by hand, but I would like for Kubernetes to do this for me, otherwise I'll have to remember to do it again the next time a new ELB is provisioned (Kubernetes upgrade, config change, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you right, you would like to adjust security policies directly from Service.yml file.

From what I see, [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/legacy-cloud-providers/blob/master/aws/aws.go) you can find a list of all the annotations that are supported at the moment.

There is one called "aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy". For me it looks exactly as the one you are looking for.

```
// ServiceAnnotationLoadBalancerSSLNegotiationPolicy is the annotation used on
// the service to specify a SSL negotiation settings for the HTTPS/SSL listeners
// of your load balancer. Defaults to AWS's default

const ServiceAnnotationLoadBalancerSSLNegotiationPolicy = "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy"
```

The link to that file is listed under [official documentation on K8s](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#aws).

Additionally, there  is a predefined policy [ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html) that uses only TLS v1.2 ( with 1.0 and 1.1 disabled).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Use like this in your service annotations:

annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-negotiation-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"

Answer (score 1):

you can use for example annotations like:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-1-2017-01
```

[ALB Ingress Controller SSL Policy Annotations](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#ssl)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the Security policy on the HTTPS listener on the Load Balancer.

Comment: I should have been more specific - I would like to avoid doing this by hand, if possible.